# Why does SQL think my column name is ambiguous?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm learning SQL (lite3) and in one of the exercises I need to check the IMDB database for movies that both Johnny Depp and Helena Bonham Carter starred in.

I came up with the following:

```
SELECT title 
FROM movies
WHERE movies.id IN (SELECT movies.id  
                    FROM movies
                    JOIN stars ON movies.id = stars.movie_id
                    JOIN people ON people.id = stars.person_id
                    WHERE name = "Jhonny Depp")
  AND movies.id IN (SELECT movies.id 
                    FROM movies
                    JOIN stars ON movies.id = stars.movie_id
                    JOIN people ON people.id = stars.person_id
                    WHERE name = "Helena Bonham Carter");
```

The console is returning

> Error: near line 1: ambiguous column name: id

`.schema` shows

```
CREATE TABLE movies 
(
    id INTEGER,
    title TEXT NOT NULL,
    year NUMERIC,
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
);

CREATE TABLE stars 
(
    movie_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    person_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY(movie_id) REFERENCES movies(id),
    FOREIGN KEY(person_id) REFERENCES people(id)
);

CREATE TABLE directors 
(
    movie_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    person_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY(movie_id) REFERENCES movies(id),
    FOREIGN KEY(person_id) REFERENCES people(id)
);

CREATE TABLE ratings 
(
    movie_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    rating REAL NOT NULL,
    votes INTEGER NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY(movie_id) REFERENCES movies(id)
);

CREATE TABLE people 
(
    id INTEGER,
    name TEXT NOT NULL,
    birth NUMERIC,
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
```

I don't understand why it's ambiguous. I'd appreciate a lot if you could be somewhat vague to just nudge me in the right direction. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your code is fine: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fapozXH2ssiTWUTa1oJhmx/0

Answer (score 0):

Have a alias name to the main select.

```
SELECT m.title FROM movies as m
WHERE movies.id IN
(
    SELECT movies.id FROM movies
    JOIN stars ON movies.id = stars.movie_id
    JOIN people ON people.id = stars.person_id
    WHERE name = "Jhonny Depp"
)
AND movies.id IN
(
    SELECT movies.id FROM movies
    JOIN stars ON movies.id = stars.movie_id
    JOIN people ON people.id = stars.person_id
    WHERE name = "Helena Bonham Carter"
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm . . . I don't see an issue with `id`.  I seen an issue with `name`.  In addition, you don't need `movies` in the subqueries.  So, what you are aiming for would seem to be:

```
SELECT m.title 
FROM movies m
WHERE m.id IN (SELECT s.movie_id  
               FROM stars s JOIN
                    people p
                    ON p.id = s.person_id
               WHERE p.name = 'Jhonny Depp'
              ) AND
      m.id IN (SELECT s.movie_id  
               FROM stars s JOIN
                    people p
                    ON p.id = s.person_id
               WHERE p.name = 'Helena Bonham Carter'
              );
```

If you qualify *all* column references, then you should not get the ambiguous column reference.  Note the use of table aliases as well.

Comment: There is no issue with name too, because the only table involved with such a column is people.